# How do I use lambda to replace for loop and still maintained functional programming?

Tags: python, functional-programming

this is the original code

```
def cage_cats(S): 
    maxtemp = 0
    temp = list(set(S))
    for i in range(len(temp)-1):
        for j in range(len(S)-1):
            if temp[i] == S[j]:
                if S[j] == S[j+1]:
                    break
                else:
                    maxtemp = max(S[j], maxtemp)

    return maxtemp
```

And below is the code I'm attempting to make to replicate the code above with different method

```
def cage_cats(S):
    temp = list(set(S))
    maxtemp = max(
        list(
            map(
                lambda i : (
                    lambda j : (
                        S[j] if temp[i] == S[j] and S[j] == S[j+1] else "None"
                    ),range(len(S)-1)
                ),range(len(temp)-1)
            )
        )
    , 0)
```

Where do I go wrong in my code? I'm kinda lost on what to do. Is there a method I can use to make the result the same as the original code but still maintain the functional programming part of it?

**Edit** :

This code is to find the maximum element that is not next to each other.

The length of input will always be even and also every number in the list will only appear 2 times.

For example:

`[1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 5]` the answer would be 5

`[1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 5, 5, 3]` the answer would be 3

`[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]` it would be 0 ( default value )

Comment: what does the original code do?

Comment: @rioV8 ChatGPT says "The function aims to find the maximum element in S that is not followed by the same element." :P

Comment: you return `"None"` in the lambda

Comment: @Nooboolean the lambda you supply to `map` does not receive the index (`i` or `j`) in your code, but instead it receives the list element. you should read up on what it does and why that's often easier to work with... no use just blindly converting stuff to what's perceived as "functional" without understanding it...

Comment: I tried 0 and it's still the same
I'm sorry for not providing more code because I thought it would be too many line so I just cut only the function I need help with.
This code is to find the maximum element that is not next to each other.
For example,  [ 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 5 ] the answer would be 5 
[1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 5, 5, 3 ] the answer would be 3

Comment: what is the answer for `[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]`

Comment: I had tried to understand it but from what I learnt is that `map` is used when I need a list in lambda but other than that I still don't understand.

Comment: @rioV8 that would be 0 ( the default value ) 
in my case I use "None" to test something and kind of forget to changed it back to 0

Comment: why do you convert the set to a list, and why don't you use the last element of the set

Comment: @rioV8 What I'm trying to do is that I want to get elements that isn't identical to each other in a set and then use that set to compare each element in a list if it is next to each other

Comment: short version: `max((a for a,b in zip(S,S[1:]) if a!=b))`

Comment: May I ask what zip do? I searched about it before and I kind of not understand it so I just give up on using it

Comment: read the doc page about `zip`

Comment: @Nooboolean basically, zip takes n lists and transform them into a list of n-tuples, index by index
`zip([0, 1], [2, 3]) == [(0, 2), (1, 3)]` so here he's zipping a list with the same list but delayed by 1, to compare an element with the next

Comment: Why are you "converting it to functional"? Is it a homework assignment which requires that, or do you find it a good idea? (because it is not)

Comment: @rioV8 but your code doesn't work cause it only checks the difference between one element and the next, so it will return stuff even if you have only dupes next to each other

Comment: @Nenri where do I calc the difference, I only compare

Comment: @rioV8 i didn't say difference as in `a - b` but as in they're different and i said "check", not "calc", problem with your code is that if you have `[..., 5, 5, 2, 2, ...]` in your list, the 2nd 5 will pass the check when it shouldn't

Comment: I posted a potential solution using `max` which can be considered a functionnal tool, i don't know if that's what you'd need

Comment: what is the answer for `[1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 1, 5, 5, 3 ]`

Comment: @rioV8 would be error because my other function checks to make sure that there can only be none or 2 numbers of the same value. so in your list got 3 2's which will not pass the check

Comment: don't you think that is an important part of the problem description

Comment: Sorry, I will edit it asap

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using only `max` and some list comprehension to replace the 2 for loops by only 1.

It works by comparing all the elements in your list with the one before and after and checking if its different to both or no

```py
S = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 5, 5, 3]
S = ["", *S, ""] # pad with values that you're sure aren't in your list
filtered_S = [b for a, b, c in zip(S, S[1:], S[2:]) if a != b != c]
sol = max(filtered_S, default=0)
# sol = 3
```

Edit :

If you want to completely replace for loops, you can also use `filter` and `map` to build `filtered_S` (`filter` does the filtering using the zipped list, and `map` takes back the element that interests us)

```py
filtered_S = map(
    lambda t: t[1], 
    filter(
        lambda t: t[0] != t[1] != t[2], zip(S, S[1:], S[2:])
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems I'm unable to do it until now because I avoid using zip because I don't understand it but now that your code worked with it I will try more to understand it.

Comment: `for` loop and list comprehension (syntax sugar for loop) is not considered functional

Comment: wait I forgot that I need to use `lambda` instead of `for `loop for a second there

Comment: @Nooboolean, edited with using filter and map instead of the list comprehension (it makes it a bit more cumbersome though in my opinion)

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to learn how to do different method like Object-oriented, Imperative, functional etc so This help a lot!

Comment: @rioV8 that's true, i edited my answer to account for that and to include a solution using `map` and `filter`

Comment: @Nenri By the way, What does `S = ["", *S, ""]` do and why it isn't considered as reassign to the first line S?

Comment: @Nooboolean it adds `""` to the start and the end of `S` and yes it reassigns, but you can just store it in a new variable instead (or use it directly as a lambda expression argument)
the `*` before `S` is a spread operator which basically gets out all the elements of S

Comment: @Nenri
so I can do it like this instead?
`S = [1,1,2,2,3,3]
temp = ["", *S, ""]`
got it Thank you.

Comment: @Nooboolean, yes, and don't forget to then use `temp` everywhere else

Comment: `sol = max(filtered_S, default=0)`

Comment: no need to convert it to a `list` when passed to `max`, `filtered_S = map(...)`

Comment: @rioV8 didn't know about default arg for max, and ye i could omit the `list`, i'm editing the answer, thanks

Comment: no need to make a list use a generator `filtered_S = (b for a, b, c in zip(S, S[1:], S[2:]) if a != b != c)`